# Can't display the first image of each DISTINCT selection

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building a photo gallery with the gallery menu. I have a table called "photographs" with columns "id, gallery_name, filename, etc."

I'm using this code to display the menu with the galleries listed:

```
        $gallery_sql = "SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name FROM {$table}";
        $gall_names = Photograph::find_by_sql($gallery_sql);
        foreach($gall_names as $page){
            $output = "<li><a href=\"index.php?subj=" . $page->gallery_name . "\">";    
            $output .= "    <img src=\"" . $page->image_path() . "\" />";
            $output .= "</a></li>";

            echo $output;
        }
```

the menu works but I can't get the first image of every distinct gallery_name selection to display as a thumbnail in the link. What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `$page->image_path()`?

Comment: It is a   `public function image_path(){
  return $this->upload_dir.'/'.$this->filename; 
 }` from a Photograph class.

Comment: Have you inspected the html source code after the page loads to see if your `<img src="...">` is a valid link?

Comment: It isn't. `<img src="images/" />`

Comment: How are you setting `$this->filename;`? Since `$page->gallery_name` is working, are you setting `$page->filename;` in a similar way?

Comment: $upload_dir="images"; and $filename; gets its value from protected static $table_name="cakes";
 protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'gallery_name', 'filename', 'type', 'caption'); Same way as gallery_name.

Comment: It looks like you are only selecting `gallery_name` in you query - `SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name FROM {$table}`. You need to add `file_name` as well. `SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name, file_name FROM {$table}`

Comment: That displays all 100+ images from the table. I want to display only distinct gallery_name values and the first image of each distinct gallery_name value as a thumbnail in the link.

Comment: Try adding a `GROUP BY` -> `SELECT DISTINCT gallery_name, file_name FROM {$table} GROUP BY gallery_name`

Comment: It worked. I can't thank you enough for this.